# image click, page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, refresh

I am working on my mobile website and I have this code on my pages:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

attached to my logo.

this code works fine on my pages but I want my index page to refresh when logo is clicked and not go back a page.

how can I do this?

thanks.

OK: PROBLEM SOLVED,

I JUST HAD TO ADD

```
<a href="PAGENAME.html">
```

TO EACH PAGE WITH THE TITLE OF THE CURRENT .html PAGE.

THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR HELP.

Comment: If i get your problem : When your on the home page, it should refresh the page right ? When your on another page, it shoud redirect you the the home page ?

Comment: hi Laurent Brieu, that is exactly right.

Comment: Ok so why don't you do : <a href="/index.php"> (replace index.php by your home page file name

Comment: hi Laurent Brieu, this is the simple way of doing this but it does not sort out my problem listed below. thanks.

Comment: Meaning home page refreshing ?

Comment: yep with my multiple index's. trouble is is there not a way to say, refresh the current page?

Comment: Can you please edit the post and write the structure of your application (files and tree view) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a relative url to redirect all clicks on the logo to the index page.

```
<a href="/"><img src="logo.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the location.href property to identify whether its in index or any other page and then decide whether to go back or refresh.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('index.') > -1)
    window.location.reload();
else
    history.go(-1);
```

Comment: WDever, I have tried your "/" version and that loads up my home home page. for example. My site is only available in mobile at the moment. As this is the case, ALL my mobile content is within "/mobile" folder.

Comment: within this mobile folder I have 4 index pages, iphone.html for iphone / ipod touch, ipad.html for ipad, android.html for android devices and index.html for everything else. Also I have a simple divert to relevant page on each of these 4 pages so the correct device is viewing the correct content. using your code on my iphone diverts me to www.xclo.co.uk which then diverts to m.xclo.co.uk then diverts me to www.xclo.co.uk/mobile/iphone.html, this is fine if viewing in my browser (safari) but upon loading this in my app, it closes the app and loads up safari. which is not what I want.

Comment: I want a simple page refresh. that refreshes the page once the logo is clicked avoiding the app closure. I hope this helps. thank you.

Comment: i dont know if you are commenting to my answer or @WDever

Comment: because I have less then 15 reputation.

Comment: Thats sad, but if my answer solved your problem , then it's ok

Comment: no it does not solve the. the problem is the same as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this, a more dynamic solution that doesn't require putting the current page url as the href on every page you can add a link like so:

```
<a href"JavaScript: location.reload(true);">refresh</a>
```

or as a button

```
<button onclick="location.reload(true);">Refresh</button>
```

or as input:

```
<input type="button" onClick="location.reload(true);" VALUE="Refresh">
```

---

Alternative javascript that would work in slightly different ways are:

```
javascript:history.go(0)
location.reload()
location.replace(location.pathname)
```

Using jquery would be -

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

but seems unecessary

You get the idea. Hope that's helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I found out using "./" works best for me